# How should I model my logic when splitting a SwiftUI view into separate subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm getting started with SwiftUI but I'm having some issues modeling my views & logic.

Let's take this very simple view, that:

- Stores an integer `value`
- Has a stepper to change `value`
- Has a button to randomize `value`
- Enables/Disable actions based on whether `value` is odd or even.
- Does some logic on appearance

```swift
struct GlobalView: View {

    @State var value: Int = 0

    var isFirstActionEnabled: Bool { value % 2 == 0 }
    func doFirstAction() { }

    var isRandomizeEnabled: Bool { value % 2 != 0 }
    func randomizeValue() {
        value = .random(in: 0...100)
    }

    func loadSomething() { }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper(
                "Value: \(value)",
                value: $value
            )

            Button(
                "First action",
                action: doFirstAction
            )
            .disabled(!isFirstActionEnabled)

            Button(
                "Randomize",
                action: randomizeValue
            )
            .disabled(!isRandomizeEnabled)
        }
        .onAppear(perform: doSomething)

    }

}
```

Of couse, this view is simple and fine by its own.

But let's say I have some more complex logic/UI/formatting/etc, and I'd like to split this view into separated subviews:

- One `ChildOneView`, that displays the stepper (and maybe handle logic of its own)
- One `ChildTwoView`, that displays and perform the first action (and maybe handle logic of its own)
- One `ParentView` that glues those two views and can randomize the value.

Here is how I implemented `ChildOneView` (along with a view model, that can manage the dependencies and be tested):

```swift
class ChildOneViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: Int = 0
    func loadSomething() { }
}
struct ChildViewOne: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ChildOneViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Stepper(
            "Value: \(viewModel.value)",
            value: $viewModel.value
        )
        .onAppear(
            perform: viewModel.loadSomething
        )
    }
}
```

Here is how I implemented `ChildTwoView` (along with a view model, that can manage the dependencies and be tested):

```swift
// Some
class ChildTwoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isEnabled: Bool = false
    func firstAction() { }
}
struct ChildViewTwo: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ChildTwoViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Button(
            "First action",
            action: viewModel.firstAction
        )
        .disabled(!viewModel.isEnabled)
    }
}
```

And here is how I defined `ParentView`:

```swift
import Combine
class ParentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let childOneViewModel: ChildOneViewModel
    let childTwoViewModel: ChildTwoViewModel
    @Published var isRandomizeEnabled: Bool = false
    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init() {
        self.childOneViewModel = .init()
        self.childTwoViewModel = .init()

        self.childOneViewModel.$value
            .map { $0 % 2 == 0 }
            .sink(receiveValue: { [childTwoViewModel] in
                childTwoViewModel.isEnabled = $0
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)

        self.childOneViewModel.$value
            .map { $0 % 2 != 0 }
            .sink(receiveValue: { [unowned self] in
                self.isRandomizeEnabled = $0
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func randomizeValue() {
        childOneViewModel.value = Int.random(in: 0...100)
    }

}

struct ParentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ParentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ChildViewOne(viewModel: viewModel.childOneViewModel)
        ChildViewTwo(viewModel: viewModel.childTwoViewModel)
        Button(
            "Randomize",
            action: viewModel.randomizeValue
        )
        .disabled(!viewModel.isRandomizeEnabled)
    }
}
```

It feels like `GlobalView` into multiple views (`ParentView`, `ChildOneView`, `ChildTwoView`) added a lot of complexity, boilerplate code and potential mistakes.

Once again, this is an example and Parent/ChildOne/ChildTwo are meant to have more logic, otherwise, `GlobalView` and this whole question is pointless.

might be thinking of this in too much of a "UIKit" way. Am I missing something obvious ?
How would you approach this ?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to remove the view model objects because SwiftUI already does what you have tried to code. In the View struct use let for read only data, state/binding for read/write.  SwiftUI calls `body` whenever those values change (no need for any Combine code). Put the state high enough in the hierarchy so it can be passed down to the Views that need it. Use computed vars to transform data from a let/state into a child View's init. Make sure to use SwiftUI's built-in formatting because it automatically updates the labels on screen when region is changed by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an opinionated subject, and as such there is no "answer". If it's your own project, do what you want in a way you feel is clean. If it's at work or a team, establish guidelines on how your team likes to abstract views if they get too big.

With that said, in general there's a balance between when your View really needs its own View Model or not. If it's truly big enough to have all its own logic or instantiated in multiple places and can't piggy-back off of a parent view's View Model, then you'll need to create another one. You don't need a parent View Model that encapsulates all the lower View Model's together, you just need a View Model for a specific View that can then pass down functionality to lower Views. Even with certain potential functionality coming from a higher View, a given View may want its own View Model to encapsulate certain things, but you wouldn't have a single View Model directly managing other View Models. If a specific child is only ever going to be put in one place with unique functionality, I will usually just put all VM code for that child within the parent VM instead of creating all the boilerplate, but again if it's needed, it's needed.

It may seem rather boilerplate-y in this example because there's not really any functionality, but it's not all that much code to create a VM and plop it in a parent VM for a child View that's got a lot going on.

Apart from splitting large Views into separate structs with their own VMs, the best optimization in terms of code clarity I feel like is abstracting small components within a single view to computed vars or functions. For example:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            header
            main
            footer
        }
    }

    var header: some View {
        // View with maybe lots of modifiers and if-else logic. Around
        // 20-30 lines max. Up to you.
    }

    var main: some View {
        // View
    }

    var footer: some View {
        // View
    }

    // UI specific funcs below ...
```

And these would all operate on a single VM. If they get a little too big, but don't need their own VM you can abstract them to a new struct and file if you want to and simply:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        header
        main
        SpecialButton()
        footer
    }
```

Where `SpecialButton()` is a `struct SpecialButton: View` elsewhere. You might need to pass a binding or closure to it.

This is all taste, but this is how I write my SwiftUI. I would only start creating VMs for Views if they truly needed it.